# W3.JS Display HTML Data {{variable}} in Octobercms Page or Partial

Tags: javascript, html, octobercms, w3.js

please help me with October CMS Code - Page or Partial, how to use them with W3.JS.

W3.JS Display HTML Data {{variable}}  in Octobercms

{{ }} this transcription use OctoberCMS for your own data

But W3.JS Display HTML Data use the same transcription

https://www.w3schools.com/w3js/w3js_display.asp

```
<div id="id01">
{{firstName}} {{lastName}}
</div>

<script>
var myObject = {"firstName" : "John", "lastName" : "Doe"};
w3.displayObject("id01", myObject);
</script>
```

it doesn't work

thank you for your help

Vasek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple you just make it string so TWIG will treat it as a string and do not parse/interpolate it.

ref: https://tutorialmeta.com/octobercms/october-cms-use-curly-brackets-twig-markup

```
<div id="id01">
{{ '{{firstName}} {{lastName}}' }}
</div>

<script>
var myObject = {"firstName" : "John", "lastName" : "Doe"};
w3.displayObject("id01", myObject);
</script>
```

> `{{ '{{firstName}} {{lastName}}' }}` -> it will output `{{firstName}} {{lastName}}` in final markup

if any doubt please comment

Comment: sure you are most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the JavaScript template part in `verbatim` filter:
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#escaping